# How to use CopyManager with connection pooled DataSource?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, c3p0, visualvm

I'm trying to use `postgres` `CopyManager.copyIn()` for batch inserts. My datasource is a c3p0 `ComboPooledDataSource`.

The sql statements are batch with:

`dataSource.getConnection().getCopyAPI().copyIn(sql, items); //pseudocode`

Now to speed up database inserts even more (hundred GB to import after pre-processing), I'm trying to send the `copyIn` command in async threads.

But does this make sense if the database is located on a single disk filesystem? Would this gain performance?

And how can I actually verify that the copyIn is using the connection pool in parallel?

I tried `VisualVM` `MBeans` screen, where i can see a single `PooledDataSource` entry. But how can I know that the pool is used and items are send to DB parallel?

Comment: To see how busy the pool is, look for numBusyConnectionsDefaultUser. That's how many Connections are checked out (as long as you are calling getConnection() without user and password arguments). Hopefully checked out means in use, although that depends on how your application is written.

Answer (score 1):

> But does this make sense if the database is located on a single disk filesystem? Would this gain performance?

If it's spinning rust it might not, and there's certainly little benefit in much concurrency. For SSDs it'll sometimes produce quite a significant improvement. Depends a lot on the drive.

> I tried VisualVM MBeans screen, where i can see a single PooledDataSource entry. But how can I know that the pool is used and items are send to DB parallel?

Look at `pg_stat_activity` in the database and see if there are multiple concurrent `COPY` commands from the app.